# React Native app crashing on start after system iOS update

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I ran into this issue a while ago: I install my app in my **iPhone** both in debug and release and it works well. However after some time (days, weeks) it starts crashing for no apparent reason on start, right after the splash screen shows up. **I suspect this happens after every iOS update.**

At first I thought this had something to do with the metro bundler not running but the app crashes both in debug and release.

I'm really just everything as described in the docs. The main problem here is a can't reproduce this error (or at least I don't know how) since it depends on an iOS update so I can't do it on the simulator, only in a real device.

**EDIT:** I got some logs from the crash, thanks to [this buddybuild guide](https://docs.buddybuild.com/troubleshooting/getting_device_logs_from_xcode.html).

The logs for Release:

> error  09:30:50.134080 +0200   assertiond  Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 19786: (os/kern) failure (0x5)
>
> error  09:30:50.134299 +0200   assertiond  Failed to start job with error  {
>       description = "Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 19786";
>       failureReason = "The process failed to exec";
>       recoverySuggestion = "Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log for more information";
>   }
>
> error  09:30:50.137082 +0200   SpringBoard [org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter] Bootstrap failed with error:
>
> error  09:30:50.137354 +0200   SpringBoard Bootstrapping failed for  with error: Error Domain=BKSProcessErrorDomain Code=1 "Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter" UserInfo {NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to bootstrap process with bundleID org.josemigallas.RealmsCounter, BKSProcessExitReason=0, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Failed to start job, NSUnderlyingError=0x282693900 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=3 "No such process" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to exec, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Consult /var/log/com.apple.xpc.launch /launchd.log for more information, NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to get valid task name port right for pid 19786}}, BSErrorCodeDescription=bootstrap-failed}

**EDIT2:** I found out it's happening in debug as well.. so updating the text a bit.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out it wasn't the updates.. but the Provisioning Profile that expires after 6 days, the application has to be rebuild and installed everytime. This happens with a free Apple developer account.

Answer (score 0):

If this is crashing in a released app, you might be able to find the crash logs by  going to **Xcode->Window->Organizer** and select the Crashes tab at the top.

If I were to guess, it sounds like it's taking too long for initialization, and so it's getting killed by the springboard app.

Comment: Thanks, I see the Organizer window empty :/
A clarification, the app crashes instantly on start up. It's after some time of installing the release version when the app starts crashing. So, it works for some days or weeks and then all of a sudden one day crashes. That's why I suspect is because of updates in iOS.

Comment: In the end I did Window > Devices and Simulators > iPhone > Open Console

Comment: Hey Mike, did you read my comment? Could you please update your answer? It doesn't really address the problem.